# How to auto update runtimeVersion in aws_synthetics_canary using Terraform?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-synthetics

**runtimeVersion**s are repeatedly deprecated in aws_synthetics_canary, and there is always need to update the runtime version every while, Is there a way to automate this process?

Example:

```
resource "aws_synthetics_canary" "canary" {
  name                 = "${var.name}"
  handler              = "up.handler"
  runtime_version      = "syn-nodejs-puppeteer-6.0" # I want to automate this part
```

Comment: You could define a variable and assign it a default value.

Comment: Still that will not automate the process, I'll still need to update the default value every while. @MarkoE

Comment: Well, even though that is true, how will you know which is the value that you need to provide?

Answer (score 1):

The runtimes seem to last about 2 years?

You could set the runtime to a variable and pass the latest supported runtime in when your pipeline applies. the cloudwatch docs have a pattern to follow to get latests https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/CloudWatch_Synthetics_Canaries_Library.html